# Open-source computer algebra systems for linux

Tags: linux, software-rec

Some years ago I used [MuPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MuPAD) as a free computer algebra system. However since 2005 it's not free anymore. So, are there any good free or even better open-source computer algebra systems for linux coming close to commercial products like mathematica or maple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/). It is GPL-licensed software and includes lots of [components](http://www.sagemath.org/links-components.html). SAGE also has a nice [tutorial](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/) for the first (and second) steps.

Comment: SAGE seems to be promising. Is it necessary to run it in a browser or is there also a "local" graphical interface (which is not a web browser)?

Comment: Is it true that maxima is a part of SAGE, i.e. everything you can do in maxima you can also do in SAGE?

Comment: @user5289 Sage provides two user interfaces, command line (or script) and the web-based notebook. There's no non-web GUI. Maxima is a part of sage and sage uses maxima automatically to solve a number of problems. You can call maxima function directly from within sage if you want to use all of maxima.

Answer (score 9):

My first suggestion would be **[Maxima](http://andrejv.github.com/wxmaxima/screenshots.html)**, but it seems I'm out of date.  Wikipedia lists several:

[Axiom](http://www.axiom-developer.org/), [Cadabra](http://cadabra.phi-sci.com/), [CoCoA](http://cocoa.dima.unige.it/), DoCon, Eigenmath, [FriCAS](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/), [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/), [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/), [Mathomatic](http://www.mathomatic.org/), Maxima, [OpenAxiom](http://www.open-axiom.org/), [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), [Reduce](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/), [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), [SINGULAR](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/), [SymPy](http://sympy.org/), [Xcas](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/giac.html)

It also has a [comparison of computer algebra systems](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems).

Comment: In particular the `wxmaxima` front end, that make it more similar to `Mathematica`.

Comment: Many of these are either fairly basic or specialized to a subfield of mathematics. Sage is an ongoing effort to combine many existing computer algebra systems into one huge system.

Answer (score 1):

I have using Cantor http://edu.kde.org/applications/all/cantor/ for mathematical models

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:  http://linuxappfinder.com/search_results?cx=partner-pub-4519499759658771%3A7235616731&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&as_q=algebra&sa=Search

Note that there are several pages.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already mentioned Maxima, another visible option is [Axiom](http://axiom-developer.org/). However, my impression is that Maxima's mindshare and userbase is greater than Axiom. However, I don't think either of these have functionality comparable to Mathematica or Maple. On the other hand, Mathematica at least is quite actively developed, and continues to improve.